# UserCreationForm KeyError 'email' in Registration page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im learning django and im trying to understand the registration progress with an UserCreationForm and a CreateView, I want to use an email as field on the registration form but they keep poping an error about KeyError 'email' on my form.

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from accountApp.models import Profile
    from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

    class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ('username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

    class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
        model = get_user_model()

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['username'].label = 'Usuario'
            self.fields['email'].label = 'Email'
```

views.py

```
    from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
    from . import forms

    class RegistrationPage(CreateView):
        template_name = 'accountApp/register.html'
        success_url =  reverse_lazy('accApp:profilepage')
        form_class = forms.CreateUserForm
```

models.py

```
    from django.db import models
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)

        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

[IMG 01 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWmf.png)

[IMG 02 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwMsp.png)

Comment: add full error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is failing here

```
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email'
```

Here you can see that UserCreationForm form you are inheriting from has no field `email`.

```
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    A form that creates a user, with no privileges, from the given username and
    password.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password"),
        strip=False,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html(),
    )
    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label=_("Password confirmation"),
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
        strip=False,
        help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username",)
        field_classes = {'username': UsernameField}

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD in self.fields:
            self.fields[self._meta.model.USERNAME_FIELD].widget.attrs.update({'autofocus': True})

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'],
                code='password_mismatch',
            )
        return password2

    def _post_clean(self):
        super()._post_clean()
        # Validate the password after self.instance is updated with form data
        # by super().
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password:
            try:
                password_validation.validate_password(password, self.instance)
            except forms.ValidationError as error:
                self.add_error('password2', error)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

You can add fields if you want to

```
first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=False, help_text='Optional.')
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.')
```

and override `save` method.

Comment: Where would you place the 3 lines with: email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text='...')?